# Python OpenCV memory leak

Tags: python, opencv, memory, gstreamer

After each execution of the code, 150 MB of memory leaks out.

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.64:554/Streaming/Channels/101')
ret_val, img = cam.read()
ret_val = cv2.imwrite(str(chat_id) + '.jpg',img)
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Most likely this is due to OpenCV. Below is the configuration OpenCV.
I'm using GStreamer, to work with the H264 stream from IP camera.

```
General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.1-dev =====================================
  Version control:               3.4.1-54-g5b868cc

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2018-03-11T16:10:52Z
    Host:                        Linux 4.13.0-36-generic x86_64
    CMake:                       3.5.1

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      YES (ver 2.2.4)
    FFMPEG:                      NO
      avcodec:                   NO
      avformat:                  NO
      avutil:                    NO
      swscale:                   NO
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   
      base:                      YES (ver 1.8.3)
      video:                     YES (ver 1.8.3)
      app:                       YES (ver 1.8.3)
      riff:                      YES (ver 1.8.3)
      pbutils:                   YES (ver 1.8.3)
    libv4l/libv4l2:              NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h
    gPhoto2:                     NO
```